# failed to return AJAX call when use_session_sid

Tags: ajax, yii

I am trying to use php's use_trans_sid, so I will have phpsessid in all urls.
But, when I set use_trans_sid to 1, AJAX call did not get result properly.
Somehow the result truncated.

When I set use_trans_sid back to 0, AJAX call get result properly again.

What would be the problem?

I am using the Yii framework.

Comment: What means `Somehow the result truncated.`. Can you show example full result and truncated?

Comment: Ok, I must clarify this: the proper term must be "the AJAX call failed". When I inspect this using Chrome developer interface (F12) then click 'Network' tab, select the request (from the list on the left), click 'Preview'. In that 'Preview' tab, I can see the truncated result. It display half of the intended view.But, on the 'Response' tab, the result is complete.

If the AJAX call success, the 'Preview' tab will show a JSON object.

Comment: I noticed that whenever I call `Yii::app()->session->sessionID` the AJAX call failed. If I `do not` call `Yii::app()->session->sessionID`, the AJAX call success. (In Chrome's Developer interface, the 'Preview' tab display the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Check ajax url requests when `use_trans_sid=1`, if they haven't phpsessid var than you need manually add it to request url as GET parameter.

`use_trans_sid=1` rewrites only page url, not js and ajax. When it using, PHP try to find session id in get parameter, if not found - created new session.

When you using  `use_trans_sid=0` ajax works, because PHP work over cookie session id

Comment: CreatoR, I have added phpsessid var in the request url of ajax request. And the ajax call still get truncated result.

Comment: In ajax targets `use_trans_sid=1` too? Can you do `var_export(session_name().':'.session_id());` with resuls in response? Check if session id equals to added var to requests and check it values. If different name - use that which printed in response, if different values - something wrong with `use_trans_sid` and you may get session id from requst var phpsessid and set it manually by `session_id($_GET['phpsessid']);`

Comment: the use_trans_sid is a variabel in php.ini conf file.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it conf may be changed in .htaccess or in the code before. That's why I ask you to do a little research. What is the results?

Comment: CreatoR, it printed out this: PHPSESSID:q08j2dqcqsb19c50l95r872pp3. The sessionid valid is match to sessionid I got. And the session name is also match.

Comment: I noticed that whenever I call `Yii::app()->session->sessionID` the AJAX result truncated. If I do not call `Yii::app()->session->sessionID`, the AJAX result is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have set php's use_trans_sid to 1.

With that, PHP will insert code to propagate session id.
In my case, PHP inserted a hidden variable in a form which has been encoded into json object.
As the result, ajax call get it as a request error (it did not get a json object).

I confirmed this by replacing the form with string like 'Hello'.
With that, PHP did not insert code to propagate session id. And ajax call get it as a good json object.

Now the problem has changed into 'how to make such interruption from PHP will not interfere ajax call?'